# Storing the value in a table column vs Calculating the value from navigation property

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, database-design

I need advice for using Entity Framework 6. Suppose the website features many products with many reviews (think Amazon.com). Assuming most visitors view products more than writing reviews, then if I want to display the average user rating for each product, should I add a `AverageReviewRating` column to store its value to (supposedly) speed up query performance?

Is this a good or bad practice? The alternative would be to access each Review from the navigation property and calculate the average rating from that. What's the recommended approach?

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Should I store the rating in a pre-calculated column or not?
    public int AverageReviewRating { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not store the average in a separate field becase

1. I will need to update it frequently
2. I will not be saving much in terms of performance

If you query using an Entity Framework context and you request an average of the review properties, the review will not be fetched. Entity Framework will generate a SQL select statement returning the average.

Something like: `SELECT AVERAGE(ReviewScore) FROM ReviewsTable Where ReviewedProductId = ProductId`

Furthermore, database denormalization should only be used when you meet serious performance problems.

Answer (score 0):

I would say if it is something huge like amazon you can pre store the calculated value.
This would help in better performance while fetching .Also you can delegate the task of updating the average to some kind of background process.